# Get the number of form inputs with different names using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, input

How to get the number of inputs in a form using `jquery` so that each group with a different name consider as one item?
For example, for the form below, we have to get 4:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="textField">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxField">
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="radioField" value="one">
    <input type="radio" name="radioField" value="two">
    <input type="radio" name="radioField" value="three">
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="radioField2" value="four">
    <input type="radio" name="radioField2" value="five">
  </div>
</form>
```

I have tried this method and am looking for a different and perhaps more optimal one:

```js
const fieldsName = [];
$('form :input').each(function(index, item) {
  fieldsName.push(item.name)
});

let uniqueFieldsName = [];

$.each(fieldsName, function(index, item) {
  if ($.inArray(item, uniqueFieldsName) === -1) {
    uniqueFieldsName.push(item);
  }
});

let itemsCount = uniqueFieldsName.length;
console.log(itemsCount);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js" integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<form>
  <input type="text" name="textField">
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxField">
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="radioField" value="one">
    <input type="radio" name="radioField" value="two">
    <input type="radio" name="radioField" value="three">
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="radioField2" value="four">
    <input type="radio" name="radioField2" value="five">
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: What have you tried  ?

Comment: @j08691 I added to the question what I had tried.
I was looking for a different and perhaps more optimistic way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
const names = $('[name]').map(function() {return this.name;});
const distinct = [...new Set(names)];
console.log(distinct.length);
```

**DEMO:**

```js
const names = $('[name]').map(function() {return this.name;});
const distinct = [...new Set(names)]
console.log(distinct.length)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <input type="text" name="textField">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxField">
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="radioField" value="one">
    <input type="radio" name="radioField" value="two">
    <input type="radio" name="radioField" value="three">
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="radioField2" value="four">
    <input type="radio" name="radioField2" value="five">
  </div>
</form>
```

**Explanation:**

- `$('[name]')` - Get all elements having name attribute.
- `.map(function() {return this.name;});` - using `.map()` method return a new Array of names from all the elements found above.
- `[...new Set(names)]` - Get distinct names from the array above.
- `distinct.length` returns the number of form inputs with different names

Answer (score -2):

You can use below given method:

```
function getRadioValue(id) {
    var ele = document.getElementsByName(id);
    for (i = 0; i < ele.length; i++) {
        if (ele[i].checked)
            return ele[i].value;
    }
    return ""
}

var formABO = getRadioValue("radioField"); // Value here
```